# RXJS - flatMap redundant usage?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, flatmap

I've read an [*article*](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) about RXJS where it also explains about `flatMap`.
I already know what's the difference and what it actually does , it flatten observable of observables to a single observable sequence. ( something like `SelectMany` in C# )

Anyway they've used `flatMap`  for a jQuery `getJson` request:

```
var responseStream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl));
  });
```

It is clear to me what's going on ( and I see this usage at many places )

But couldn't it be a simple : ( *The following code doesn't work but still I want to know why,becuase logically it seems that it should work*)

```
var responseStream = requestStream
  .map(function(requestUrl) {
    return jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl);
  });
```

?

**Question**

What is the difference between those two snippets ?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/staltz/8jFJH/59/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code in second snippet is not working as you expected because it creates Observable of promises(not values). `map` operator will not unwrap promises returned from it.

So, you still need `flatMap` or similar operator to unwrap promises, but you can return promise directly in it, and simplify code as following:

```
var responseStream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return jQuery.getJSON(requestUrl);
  });
```

Comment: How come flatMap knows to unwrap promises  , where it should unwrap observables ??

Comment: it supports promises too, above that you can return array from it and it also will flatten it.

Comment: not sure where to point for rxjs5, but for rxjs4: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md

Answer (score 1):

You have more than one question here, so I'd try to answer both:

1. You wonder that it supports promises, but currently it does, see [the examples](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#mergemap). The problem is that as long as it is not documented they will be able to remove this support in future, so you could just wrap every `Promise` into `Observable.fromPromise` or similar right now.
2. Internally `flatMap` most likely casts Promise to Observable while `map` does not, that's why your code snippet won't call anything: Observables are lazy and you would need to subscribe to every Observable after the map function in order to actually run the Promise